# How can I deconstruct a VBA .xlam project into .cls and .frm files?

Tags: excel, vba, version-control

I'm currently developing an Excel Add-in written in VBA and using Excel with its Visual Basic editor. My problem is that Excel will compile the code into a single {Addin}.xlam file that's useless for version control and restricts me to only using the Visual Basic editor, which is difficult and awkward to use on Mac.

I'm aware of tools like Rubberduck and XlTools, but these all seem to be restricted to working only within Excel. What I'm looking for is a CLI tool with convenient functions like:

`vba build src/`  (constructs a workable .xlam from src files)
`vba extract addin.xlam` (extracts src files from .xlam)

This would be really helpful so that I can use version control as well as Visual Studio to write VBA.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [VSTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office). Anyway, IMO this [question is off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO

Comment: Or you can try ExcelDna https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna  ... here is a quick start with ExcelDna Ribbon https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Samples/tree/master/Ribbon

Comment: @Storax from what I've seen VSTO's don't allow UDFs which are pretty fundamental to my Add-in. Where would you suggest I post this instead?

Comment: @Bilal I'm actually giving ExcelDna a go at the moment - it's great in the sense that I can develop in C# and Visual Studio, but it doesn't have the Mac support that VBA has.

Comment: @bgordon Well, there's python based alternative XLWings https://www.xlwings.org/ which works on mac as well, but again the UDF supports is only available for Windows.

Comment: @Bilal I've looked at xlwings in the past but it doesn't fit my use case which is to create an Add-in that I can distribute to clients. It looks as if xlwings requires users to having Python installed, also I don't think xlwings gives me the same flexibility to create userforms and customise the ribbon in the same way as VBA.